# Subscribing the collection (Meteor)

Tags: javascript, meteor, admin

I have some specific problem.
I use MeteorJS and installed yogiben:admin. I tried to build some schema, but I have an error after updating something.
I want to add that I have subpages in page, maybe that's the problem?

That's what I get after adding items to my invoice:
http://s7.postimg.org/l0q52l27v/error.png

As I can see in the picture, the problem is with some modifier and with "After.Update.sum". I use function that use "sum".

In my "server/collections/invoices_item.js"
I have:

```
InvoicesItem.after.update(function(userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier, options) {
var sum = 0; InvoicesItem.find({ invoiceId: doc.invoiceId }).map(function(item) { sum += item.amount; }); Invoices.update({ _id: doc.invoiceId }, { $set: { totalAmount: sum }});
});
```

Than I saw that problem could be with "totalAmount:sum". I use Chrome, so I tried "console.log()" to see if the page takes my collection.
And it doesn't.

I use Chrome, so I tried to see what the console will give me. I have something like this: http://s4.postimg.org/rusm4wx9p/fakturka.png

I did sth like that in my code on server side:

```
Meteor.publish("fakturka", function(invoiceId) {
    return Invoices.find({_id:invoiceId,ownerId:this.userId}, {});
});
```

And did that on client side:

```
this.InvoicesNewInsertController = RouteController.extend({ 
template: "InvoicesNew",            
    yieldTemplates: {
        'InvoicesNewInsert': { to: 'InvoicesNewSubcontent'}         
    },    
    onBeforeAction: function() {
        /*BEFORE_FUNCTION*/
        this.next();
    },    
    action: function() {
        if(this.isReady()) { this.render(); } else { this.render("InvoicesNew"); this.render("loading", { to: "InvoicesNewSubcontent" });}
        /*ACTION_FUNCTION*/
    },    
    isReady: function() {               
        var subs = [
            Meteor.subscribe("invoices_item"),
            Meteor.subscribe("invoiceeeee"),
            Meteor.subscribe("customers"),
            Meteor.subscribe("fakturka", this.params.invoiceId),
            Meteor.subscribe("invoices_item_empty_faktura"),
            Meteor.subscribe("invoices_itemss_faktura", this.params.invoiceId)
        ];
        var ready = true;
        _.each(subs, function(sub) {
            if(!sub.ready())
                ready = false;
        });
        return ready;
    },    
    data: function() {              
        return {
            params: this.params || {},
            invoices_item: InvoicesItem.find({}, {}),
            invoiceeeee: Invoices.find({}, {}),
            customers: Customers.find({}, {}),
            fakturka: Invoices.findOne({_id:this.params.invoiceId}, {}),
            invoices_item_empty_faktura: InvoicesItem.findOne({_id:null}, {}),
            invoices_itemss_faktura: InvoicesItem.find({invoiceId:this.params.invoiceId}, {})
        };
        /*DATA_FUNCTION*/
    },    
    onAfterAction: function() {
    }
});
```

I'm sorry for so much code, but I really want to solve that problem and I want to give so much info as I could. Please, help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

After removing that code from: both/collections/invoices.js

```
Schemas={};
Schemas.Invoicess = new SimpleSchema({
    invoiceNumber:{
        type:Number
    },
    date_issued:{
        type:Date
    },
    date_due:{
        type:Date
    },
    customerId:{
        type:String
    },
    totalAmount:{
        type:String
    }
});
Invoices.attachSchema(Schemas.Invoicess);
```

"fakturka" is visible. After adding that code - "fakturka" in undefined.